# Timer does not invalidate

Tags: timer, swift3

I can not invalidate a Swift Timer.

When defining my objects and variables I declare the timer with

```
var scoreTimer = Timer()
```

I start the timer when two objects collide with this line:

```
scoreTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(updatePassengerScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

My updatePassengerScore method looks like this

```
    passengerScore -= 1
    scoreLabel.text = String(passengerScore)
```

When another collision is detected, I try to stop the timer with

```
scoreTimer.invalidate()
```

but the variable passengerScore is still decreasing and I do not have a clue why this is the case.
Does anyone have a clue hoe to solve this and make the Timer stop? Every Thread I read says that scoreTimer.invalidate() should actually stop the timer. I am really confused :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be starting multiple timers.  If you hit the line of code that creates a timer before the current one has been invalidated, then you will have two active timers, only one of which you can invalidate.

To prevent this possibility, call `invalidate` on `scoreTimer` before creating a new timer:

```
scoreTimer.invalidate()
scoreTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.05, target: self, selector: #selector(updatePassengerScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

---

The other way to handle it is to change `scoreTimer` to an optional, and then only create a timer if `scoreTimer` is `nil`.

```
var scoreTimer: Timer?

...

if scoreTimer == nil {
    scoreTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(...
}

...

scoreTimer?.invalidate()
scoreTimer = nil
```