# Invalidating a Timer in SwiftUI doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Timer` object within my view:

```swift
@State var timer: Timer?
```

Inside the view's body, I start the timer when the value of `popup` changes to `true`, and I invalidate the timer when `viewModel.present` changes to `true`.

```swift
var body: some View {
  /* ... */
  .onChange(of: viewModel.popup) { popup in guard popup else { return }; setupTimer() }
  .onChange(of: viewModel.present) { present in guard present else { return }; resetTimer() }
}
```

In `setupTimer()`, I create the timer instance:

```swift
private func setupTimer() {
  guard timer == nil else { return }
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 8.0, repeats: false, block: { _ in
    // This code won't stop running!
  })
}
```

Next, in `resetTimer()`, I invalidate and remove the timer:

```swift
private func resetTimer() {
  timer?.invalidate()
  timer = nil
  // ...
}
```

But the timer continues to run. I'm not sure why `timer?.invaludate()` fails to work; I've used breakpoints to assure that

1. `setupTimer()` is indeed only called *once* such that only a single timer is running (as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192150/timer-does-not-invalidate))
2. `self.timer` is non-`nil` when invalidating within `resetTimer` (as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34507799/swift-invalidate-timer-doesnt-work))

Any ideas on what is going wrong here? I'm running this program in macOS 12.2.1.

**Edit:** Ok, so after some investigation, I've seemed to narrow down the problem. It seems as though the timer is successfully invalidated when `setupTimer()` is called within a tap gesture or action by the user. However, if `setupTimer()` is called "automatically" within a view (i.e. via `onAppear`, `onChange`, etc.) then it cannot be invalidated. So the new question I have is: why is this? Why can I not call `setupTimer()` within `onAppear`/`onChange` and cancel the timer?

Comment: Your understanding about State wrapper is not 100% correct, State cannot and did not design for tracking a reference type! Your code should not and must work, because State doing its job. You should change your approach for using observed object.

Comment: @swiftPunk Odd though, the code seems to work in some cases even when the State wrapper is used; so, I'm not sure this is the root of the issue.

Comment: State wrapper is for value type designed! StateObject wrapper is for reference type!

Answer (score 2):

There could be some other code (that you are not showing) affecting the timer, or maybe
it does not work well on macOS 12.2.1. However, here is a simple test that works well for me,
on macos 12.3 (the only one I have) using xcode 13.3, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Does this code work for you?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timer: Timer?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Button(action: {setupTimer()}) {
                Text("start")
            }
            Button(action: {resetTimer()}) {
                Text("reset")
            }
        }.frame(width: 333, height: 333)
        .onAppear {
           setupTimer()
        }
    }
    
    private func setupTimer() {
        guard timer == nil else { return }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            // This code stop running when timer invalidate
            print("----> timer running")
        })
    }
    
    private func resetTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
}
```

Note that in your code, after `resetTimer()` is called any change in `viewModel.popup` may trigger
`setupTimer()` again, and so the timer starts again since it is nil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, your code works. I edited my original question with some additional findings.

Comment: updated my answer with `.onAppear`, and it still works well for me. Does this not work for you?